# Problems with Hangman in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

```js
var words = ['NISSAN', 'LAMBORGHINI', 'AUDI', 'TOYOTA', 'BMW', 'MERCEDES', 'HONDA', 'HYUNDAI', 'VOLKSWAGEN', 'PORSCHE'];
var score = 0;
var fails = 0;
var displayedWord = [];
str2 = "";
usedLetters = "";


var randomItem = words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)];

function startBtn(ScorePastGame) {
document.getElementById("startmessage").value = "";
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('enableLetters');
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
inputs[i].disabled = false;
}
    randomItem = words[Math.floor(Math.random()*words.length)];
    var i = 0;
    newWord = "";

    for (var i = 0; i< randomItem.length; i++) {
        newWord += "#";
    }

    var fails = 0;
    console.log(randomItem);
    document.getElementById("fail").value = fails;
    document.getElementById("hangman").value = newWord;

    if (ScorePastGame && ScorePastGame !=0)
    {
        score = ScorePastGame;
    }
    else
    {
        score = 0;
    }
    fails = 0;
}

function clickButton(letter) {
    var txtRandomword = document.getElementById("hangman").value;
    var WrongLetters = document.getElementById("startmessage").value;
    var liveNum = document.getElementById("fail").value;
    var Fail = true;

    if (randomItem.includes(letter))
    {
        for (var k = 0; k < randomItem.length; k++)
        {
            if(randomItem.charAt(k) == letter)
            {
                newWord = newWord.substr(0,k) + letter + newWord.substr(k + 1);
            }

        }
        document.getElementById("hangman").value = newWord;

        if (!newWord.includes("#"))
        {
    alert("You win!");
    fails = 0;
            score++;
            document.getElementById("score").value = score;
            startBtn(score);
        }

    }
    else
    {
        fails++;
        document.getElementById("fail").value = fails;

        if (fails > 6) {
    alert("You lose!");
    fails = 0;
    usedLetters = "";
            startBtn();
        }
    }
    usedLetters += letter + " ";
    document.getElementById("startmessage").value = usedLetters;
}
```

```css
table{
  background-color: thistle;
  margin: 0px auto;
  margin-top: 13%;
}
.enableLetters,
#score,
#fail,
#hangman,
#startmessage:disabled {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <table border="1">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4" style="text-align: right">
            <label for="score">Score: </label>
            <input type="text" id="score" name="score" value="0" size="2" checked="valid()" disabled/><br>
            <label for="fail">Fails (6): </label>
            <input type="text" id="fail" name="fail" value="0" size="2" disabled/>
          </td>
          <td colspan="7" style="text-align: center">
            <label for="hangman"></label>
            <input type="text" id="hangman" name="hangman" value="   ---Hangman---   " disabled/><br>
            <label for="startmessage"></label>
            <input type="text" id="startmessage" name="startmessage" value="Click Start to get a word." disabled/>
          </td>
          <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center">
            <label for="start"></label>
            <input type="button" id="start" name="start" value="Start" onclick="startBtn()"/>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: center"><input type="button" class="enableLetters" value="A" onClick="clickButton('A')" disabled/></td>
          <td style="text-align: center"><input type="button" class="enableLetters" value="B" onClick="clickButton('B')" disabled/></td>
          <td style="text-align: center"><input type="button" class="enableLetters" value="C" onClick="clickButton('C')" disabled/></td>
          <td style="text-align: center"><input type="button" class="enableLetters" value="D" onClick="clickButton('D')" disabled/></td>
          <td style="text-align: center"><input type="button" class="enableLetters" value="E" onClick="clickButton('E')" disabled/></td>
          <td style="text-align: center"><input type="button" class="enableLetters" value="F" onClick="clickButton('F')" disabled/></td>
          <td style="text-align: center"><input type="button" class="enableLetters" value="G" onClick="clickButton('G')" disabled/></td>
          <td style="text-align: center"><input type="button" class="enableLetters" value="H" onClick="clickButton('H')" disabled/></td>
          <td style="text-align: center"><input type="button" class="enableLetters" value="I" onClick="clickButton('I')" disabled/></td>
          <td style="text-align: center"><input type="button" class="enableLetters" value="J" onClick="clickButton('J')" disabled/></td>
          <td style="text-align: center"><input type="button" class="enableLetters" value="K" onClick="clickButton('K')" disabled/></td>
          <td style="text-align: center"><input type="button" class="enableLetters" value="L" onClick="clickButton('L')" disabled/></td>
          <td style="text-align: center"><input type="button" class="enableLetters" value="M" onClick="clickButton('M')" disabled/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: center"><input type="button" class="enableLetters" value="N" onClick="clickButton('N')" disabled/></td>
                <td style="text-align: center"><input type="button" class="enableLetters" value="O" onClick="clickButton('O')" disabled/></td>
                <td style="text-align: center"><input type="button" class="enableLetters" value="P" onClick="clickButton('P')" disabled/></td>
                <td style="text-align: center"><input type="button" class="enableLetters" value="Q" onClick="clickButton('Q')" disabled/></td>
                <td style="text-align: center"><input type="button" class="enableLetters" value="R" onClick="clickButton('R')" disabled/></td>
                <td style="text-align: center"><input type="button" class="enableLetters" value="S" onClick="clickButton('S')" disabled/></td>
                <td style="text-align: center"><input type="button" class="enableLetters" value="T" onClick="clickButton('T')" disabled/></td>
                <td style="text-align: center"><input type="button" class="enableLetters" value="U" onClick="clickButton('U')" disabled/></td>
                <td style="text-align: center"><input type="button" class="enableLetters" value="V" onClick="clickButton('V')" disabled/></td>
                <td style="text-align: center"><input type="button" class="enableLetters" value="W" onClick="clickButton('W')" disabled/></td>
                <td style="text-align: center"><input type="button" class="enableLetters" value="X" onClick="clickButton('X')" disabled/></td>
                <td style="text-align: center"><input type="button" class="enableLetters" value="Y" onClick="clickButton('Y')" disabled/></td>
                <td style="text-align: center"><input type="button" class="enableLetters" value="Z" onClick="clickButton('Z')" disabled/></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm writing a Hangman game using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. After searching through the net high and low I'm still unable to figure out how to solve the problem I'm facing. So how the Hangman game works is that the user will click on the letter and the letters they clicked will be shown on the box above. My problem now is that I can't stop the same letter from appearing on the box and that affects the number of fails.

[image]

Somehow my code to clear the box after win/lose always result with the last letter the user clicked.
[image]

Please advise on how I should change my code thanks!

Comment: usedLetters += letter + " "; is your problem for your second query. Its outside the else if and is getting executed when win lose occurs.

Comment: @Squiggs. Oh my bad! Yup it works fine after I fixed it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out already. By converting the output into an array, I'm able to remove the duplicate letters. A simple .length of the new Set also fix the fails from counting more than it should.

```
    usedLetters += letter;
    const wrong = usedLetters.split('');
    let duplicateLetters = [...new Set(wrong)];
    document.getElementById("startmessage").value = duplicateLetters;
    document.getElementById("fail").value = duplicateLetters.length;
```